# RequestMapping with POST and JSON in SpringMVC not running

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

This is my Controller:

```
package com.hodor.booking.controller;

import com.audi.interview.booking.jpa.domain.Vehicle;
import com.audi.interview.booking.service.VehicleService;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/vehicles")
@Api(value = "vehicles", description = "Vehicle resource endpoint")
public class VehicleController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VehicleController.class);

    @Autowired
    private VehicleService vehicleService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Vehicle> index() {
        log.debug("Getting all vehicles");
        return vehicleService.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json")
        public void addVehicle(@RequestBody Car car, Vehicle vehicle) {
            log.debug("Inserting vehicle");
            Vehicle testVehicle1 = new Vehicle();
            testVehicle1.setLicensePlate("M-1234");
            testVehicle1.setModel("M5");
            testVehicle1.setColor("Grey");
            testVehicle1.setActive(true);
            testVehicle1.setVin("8765-4321");
            testVehicle1.setValidTill(DateUtils.addYears(new Date(), 1));
            vehicleService.saveVehicle(testVehicle1);
        }
    }
}
```

Now "@RequestBody" and "Car" cannot be resolved. I am new to Java and Spring and I followed documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-uri-templates

How can I consume JSON data sent in my POST request?

Comment: There is no import for RequestBody and Car classes. Also, `log.debug("Inserting vehicle");` outside a method doesn't make sense. Also, Are you expecting both car and vehicle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having controller method signature like this:

```
public void addVehicle(@RequestBody Car car, Vehicle vehicle) {

}
```

I am assuming that - (Vehicle vehicle) is having little or no significance as you can not pass two dtos to your controller method - Ref - [Spring MVC controller with multiple @RequestBody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690736/spring-mvc-controller-with-multiple-requestbody). If thats the case, then you can probably remove that from your method signature.

Then you can create Car as a JSON structure and pass it on to your controller using any REST client which should work for you. Ref - [Using Postman to test REST persistence endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596904/using-postman-to-test-rest-persistence-endpoints/36597816#36597816)

Comment: Yes, only one object I need (vehilce one), thank you! Also I had to `import RequestBody` like Bruno suggested.

Comment: Glad that it helped you!